# Browser scroll, offsets and math

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm using virtual infinite scroll package from https://github.com/daybrush/infinite-viewer

And I'm trying to manipulate with inner content, so I can scroll any element to viewport **programmatically**.

*For example we have some divs inside:*
[image]

and when clicking on number of the div - it brings into viewport regardless of scroll position, zoom or div position

[image]

---

I don't have even the idea of approach... It is something like:

- Get divs bounding rect
- Adjust to parent scroll
- Adjust to zoom level
- Calculate target zoom - to fit width (with padding)
- Calculate X,Y to scroll to
- Bring the div (go to div)

But no luck yet...

- Demo: https://69252v.csb.app/
- Original Issue: https://github.com/daybrush/infinite-viewer/issues/61

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to [Daybrush](https://github.com/daybrush) the solution looks like

```
function navigateToPage(pageId) {
  const viewportElement = infiniteViewer.getViewport();
  const pageElement = document.querySelector(`[id="${pageId}"]`);
  const viewportRect = viewportElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const pageRect = pageElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const zoom = infiniteViewer.getZoom();
  const offsetLeft = (pageRect.left - viewportRect.left) / zoom;
  const offsetTop = (pageRect.top - viewportRect.top) / zoom;
  const pageWidth = pageRect.width / zoom;
  const pageHeight = pageRect.height / zoom;
  const nextZoom = 2;

  infiniteViewer.setTo({
    x: - infiniteViewer.getContainerWidth() / 2 / nextZoom + offsetLeft + pageWidth / 2,
    y: -infiniteViewer.getContainerHeight() / 2 / nextZoom + offsetTop + pageHeight / 2,
    zoom: nextZoom,
    duration: 300,
  });
}
```